# Markdown Python: Why is there a carriage return before <p> in a list produced by markdown?

Tags: django, markdown

I'm using python markdown 2.1.1. When I try to markdown a list, why is there a carriage return before

in the list? e.g.,

```
text = u" - this is a paragraph\r\n\r\n - this is a line\r\n"
markdown.markdown(text)
# produces: u'<ul>\n<li>\n<p>this is a paragraph</p>\n</li>\n<li>\n<p>this is a line</p>\n</li>\n</ul>'
```

According to the [Markdown Syntax](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#list), the expected output should be

```
u'<ul>\n<li><p>this is a paragraph</p></li>\n<li>\n<p>this is a line</p>\n</li>\n</ul>'
```

No `\n` before and after the `<p>` element, right?
This makes the page really ugly because I'm styling the block using `white-space: pre-line`, so the output would look like

```
- 
   this is a paragraph

-  this is a line
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Markdown does not obey the syntax completely. Use [markdown2](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/markdown2), which normally behaves better.

````
>>> import markdown2
>>> print markdown2.markdown(u" - this is a paragraph\r\n\r\n - this is a line\r\n")
<ul>
<li><p>this is a paragraph</p></li>
<li><p>this is a line</p></li>
</ul>

# using fenced-code-blocks
>>> print markdown2.markdown('\n\n```python\nprint('Hello')\n```', extras=['fenced-code-blocks'])
<div class="codehilite"><pre><code><span class="k">print</span><span class="p">(</span><span class="s">&quot;Hello&quot;</span><span class="p">)</span>
</code></pre></div>
````

*Note*, you need to write two `'\n'` before the first ```` ``` ```` to enable [the regexp matching of fenced-code-blocks](https://github.com/trentm/python-markdown2/blob/master/lib/markdown2.py#L1513).

Comment: Thanks it works! However I cannot get markdown2's fenced-code-block working as described.. Is there something similar to markdown1's codehilite extension in markdwon2?

Comment: @blurrcat What's the problem then? I've updated the answer to some demo

Comment: Yes, it's the `\n`s.. I don't think this is a good idea, as the 'fence' is used to eliminate the need to type in indents, now you have to type 2 `\n`s.. It's not quite compatible with my client-side markdown as well

Comment: @blurrcat maybe modify the regular expression by removing the first `'\n'` locally and ask the author for the reason of two `\n` there?